# A concise way of representing complexities.

Tags: computer-science, computational-complexity

Some symbols used in computer science should have a simpler definition.

Consider the equivalence relation $(0, a \ne 0, \infty) \sim (<, =, >)$ on $L = \lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \frac{f(n)}{g(n)} \in \{0, a, \infty\}.$ We define $(o, O, \Theta, \Omega, \omega) \sim (<, \le, =, \ge, >)$ where $f(n) = X(g(n))$ and $X \in (o, O, \Theta, \Omega, \omega).$

I'm hoping that someone can clean this up. Right now, the only flaw is that the alternative definition might be hard to understand unless you already know the standard definition.

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding the question. What exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: `We define (o,O,Θ,Ω,ω)∼ ... where ... X∈(o,O,Θ,Ω,ω)` How is that *not* circular? Then, assuming you cleaned up the definition, how do you disambiguate e.g. $f=g$ between $f \equiv g\,$ vs. $\,f=Θ(g)$?